# Is there a way to force a product search to sort results based on certain keywords?

Tags: formula, search, product, salesfoce, sortorder

When a customer searches for let's say "battery" or "batteries" in the search in the header navbar on the site, the results page typically lists a handfull of other products that include batteries, and then much further down the list, the search results also list the actual battery or batteries as separate products. Is there a way to force this product search to sort results based on certain keywords, "battery" or "batteries" and force it to list those first?

Comment: Out of the box - no. You can influence the search results [some](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdVkqUAF/admin-control-over-search-top-results) but certainly not in this dynamic fashion.

Comment: Thanks, that's too bad :-/